# Socket em Java que envia e recebe

Tags: java, servidor, socket

Estou realizando um projeto de faculdade e estou utilizando um microcontrolador ESP8266.
De início, queria criar um SocketServer e um SocketClient em Java, que fossem capazes de tanto receber mensagens quanto enviar um para o outro, não precisa ter conexão multithread nem nada do tipo, pode ser conexão para um client apenas, o que preciso fazer é o seguinte para ilustrar a situação:

1 - Ler um cartão RFID conectado ao ESP8266, conectar ao SocketServer e enviar esta string contendo os 8 caracteres do cartão de RFID apresentado para o SocketServer.

2 - SocketServer recebe estes caracteres, e envia uma resposta para o SocketClient, assim, ele consegue tratar do outro lado a minha resposta de acordo.

Porém, como envolve Java e C (Programação p/ Arduino) do outro lado, gostaria de me certificar que isso funcione primeiro em Java(Server)-Java(Client). Dei uma pesquisada em vários exemplos, mas nenhum atende minhas necessidades.

Answer (score 1):

Uma observação: Uma aplicação cliente-servidor na qual os dois enviam e recebem mensagens é tipicamente multi thread, não tem outra saída.
Primeiro segue o código do servidor. É uma aplicação console que envia e recebe mensagens para um cliente. Cria-se um serverSocket em uma determinada porta e fica aguardando uma conexão. Após a conexão a aplicação torna-se multithread. O loop dentro do construtor lê strings do console e envia-as para o cliente. O loop do método run lê as strings do cliente e imprimi-as no console.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class SrvThread extends Thread {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    static DataOutputStream ostream = null;
    static int port = 9090;//porta para comunicacao.
    DataInputStream istream  = null;
    String MRcv= "";
    static String MSnd= "";

    SrvThread(){
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Aguardando conexão...");
        socket = serverSocket.accept();//aguarda conexao com o cliente.
        System.out.println("Conexão Estabelecida.");
        ostream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        istream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        this.start();//inicia uma nova thread. O metodo run é executado.

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Mensagem: ");
            String MSnd = console.nextLine(); //le string do console
            ostream.writeUTF(MSnd);//envia string para o cliente.
            ostream.flush();
       }
    } catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
      }
  }

  public void run(){
      try {
          while(true){
              MRcv = istream.readUTF();//le as strings do cliente
              System.out.println("Remoto: "+MRcv);
          }
      } catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    new SrvThread();
  }
}
```

Segue o código do cliente. Cria-se um socket cliente com o host e a porta como parâmetro. OBS: A porta deve ser a mesma usada no servidor. O resto do código é semelhante ao código do servidor.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CliThread extends Thread {

    static DataOutputStream ostream = null;
    DataInputStream istream = null;
    static String host = "";
    static int port = 9090;//porta para comunicacao. Deve ser a mesma do servidor.
    Socket socket = null;
    String MRcv= "";
    static String MSnd= "";


    CliThread(){
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", port);//conecta com o servidor.
            System.out.println("Conectado....");
            this.start();//comeca uma nova thread. O metodo run é executado.
            ostream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            istream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

            while(true){
                System.out.println("Mensagem: ");
                String MSnd = console.nextLine();//le mensagem do console.
                ostream.writeUTF(MSnd);//manda mensagem para o servidor.
                ostream.flush();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
  }

  public void run(){
      while (true) {
          try {        
              MRcv = istream.readUTF();//le mensagem do servidor.
              System.out.println("Remoto: " + MRcv);
          } catch(Exception e) {}
      }
  }


  public static void main(String args[]){
      new CliThread(); 
  }
}
```